# Understanding Animated and Keyboard events

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I come from a react-background and just started working on React-Native project.

while, my work doesn't specifically deal with hardcode react-native (more like managing state using redux, passing the data to the frontend etc)

I was still trying to comprehend the code written by one of my peer.

This is what he have done written in general (showing only the relavent code

```
class Signup extends PureComponent {

  state = { 
    email: '', 
    password: '', 
    errorMessage: null 
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.keyboardHeight = new Animated.Value(0);
    this.imageHeight = new Animated.Value(90);
  }

  componentWillMount () {
    this.keyboardWillShowSub = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillShow', this.keyboardWillShow);
    this.keyboardWillHideSub = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillHide', this.keyboardWillHide);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.keyboardWillShowSub.remove();
    this.keyboardWillHideSub.remove();
  }

  keyboardWillShow = (event) => {
    Animated.parallel([
      Animated.timing(this.keyboardHeight, {
        duration: event.duration,
        toValue: event.endCoordinates.height,
      }),
      Animated.timing(this.imageHeight, {
        duration: event.duration,
        toValue: IMAGE_HEIGHT_SMALL,
      }),
    ]).start();
  };

  keyboardWillHide = (event) => {
    Animated.parallel([
      Animated.timing(this.keyboardHeight, {
        duration: event.duration,
        toValue: 0,
      }),
      Animated.timing(this.imageHeight, {
        duration: event.duration,
        toValue: IMAGE_HEIGHT,
      }),
    ]).start();
  };

  handleLogin = () => {
    // TODO Using Redux
  }

  render() {
    const {email, password, fullName, username} = this.state;

    return (  
      <Animated.View style={{ paddingBottom: this.keyboardHeight, flex: 1 }}>
```

I am unable to comprehend this code and for some reason, react-native docs have been no good.

Here are all the things which seems hard to comprehend.

**First:** `this.keyboardHeight = new Animated.Value(0);`

How can we use `new Animated.Value(0);` to set keyboard height?

**Second:** In our `componentWillMount() {` he have done

```
componentWillMount () {
    this.keyboardWillShowSub = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillShow', this.keyboardWillShow);
    this.keyboardWillHideSub = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillHide', this.keyboardWillHide);
  }
```

i.e assigning/attaching event listener to `this.keyboardWillShowSub` and `this.keyboardWillHideSub`? which will be triggered whenever we show or hide/keyboard (correct?)

**Third:** What does this code do?

```
Animated.parallel([
      Animated.timing(this.keyboardHeight, {
        duration: event.duration,
        toValue: 0,
      }),
      Animated.timing(this.imageHeight, {
        duration: event.duration,
        toValue: IMAGE_HEIGHT,
      }),
    ]).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi I will try my best to give you idea about those lines of codes.

First `this.keyboardHeight = new Animated.Value(0);` - As far as I understood initially when we land on that particular page we do not want animated keyboard popup on `componentDidMount` that's why animated value is 0.

Second We give those methods inside `componentWillMount` so whenever those methods called `componentWillMount` trigger and that `new Animated.Value(0);` will get the keyboard height and keyboard will pop up (Animated).

Third I assume developer intended to change the height of the image on keyboard popup paralelly.

Hopefully what I explained, gave you an idea what those lines are intended to do.